# phpunit tests failing after going to php 8.0 because of "Unknown named parameter"

Tags: php, php-8

We are preparing to move to php 8.0.15 once some third party libraries we require are ready for it.

Our centralized setUp() function for unit tests handles constructorArg population for our class mocks.

Using phpunit v9.5.14 currently, we get failed tests with the response ***Error : Unknown named parameter $User***

We are not using named parameters in our codebase anywhere that we are aware of.

```
if (empty($this->constructorArgs)) {
    $this->constructorArgs = array('User');
}
if (!empty($this->constructorArgs) && is_array($this->constructorArgs)) {
    foreach ($this->constructorArgs as $classname) {
        if (is_array($classname)) {
            $args[key($classname)] = current($classname);
            $classname = key($classname);
        } else {
            if ($classname == "Twig" || $classname == "Twig\Environment") {
                $args[$classname] = TwigFactory::mockTwig();
            } else {
                $args[$classname] = $this->getMockBuilder($classname)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
            }
        }
        $container->set($classname, $args[$classname]);
    }
}

$this->mock = $this->getMockBuilder($this->class)
    ->setMethods($this->methods)
    ->setConstructorArgs($args)
    ->getMock();   <-- Error states this line, unfortunately no stack trace
```

The constructorArgs are populated into the setup like this:

```
$this->constructorArgs = array('User','AnotherClass', 'YetAnother');
```

We've tried everything we can think of, thinking that maybe it was something to do with the casing of the variable name in the class construct, i.e. "User $user" but so far nothing has resolved this.

Comment: Is this Laravel centric or PHPUnit? Is that version of phpunit written for PHP 8? Top of their page, "PHPUnit 9.5 requires PHP 7.3"  Those array key behavior changes...

Comment: @ficuscr this is phpunit related (no Laravel in this project). We are going from php 7.4.x to php 8.0.x and in this branch using php 8 and phpunit 9 we are getting the error now where we didn't before (and Sebastian Bergmann has stated that phpunit will not support named parameters - which you'd think wouldn't matter since we aren't using any - yet here we are somehow)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't even sure phpunit was compatible but see it should be. Sorry, can't help more with out being able to better test, maybe highlight the line that actually throws the error a bit better?

Comment: What makes you think that the code you pasted is the cause of the error? Are you getting a stack trace?

Comment: This is probably not related to PHPUnit. See [this page](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/named-parameters#named-params-call_user_func_array) regarding the use of `call_user_func_array()` parameters in PHP 8.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I edited to point out where the error is coming from. I've gone through the options a few times already today in the page you linked as it seemed very related when I found it on google as well - have tried changing around to make it numeric keys, string keys, and none of that works. we don't feel like we're doing anything too abnormal which makes it harder because I haven't found anyone with similar issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before we begin, let's create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```php
class User {}

class Example {
     public User $user;

     public function __construct(User $user) {
          $this->user = $user;
     }
}

class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
     public function testExample() {
          $args = [];
          $args['User'] = $this->getMockBuilder('User')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

          $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Example::class)
                ->setConstructorArgs($args)
                ->getMock();

          $this->assertTrue(true);
      }
}
```

Running with PHP 7.4 and PHPUnit 9.5.14, this passes; with PHP 8.0 and the same library, it gives the error you report:

> Error: Unknown named parameter $User

Actually, we can simplify a bit further: rather than `$args['User'] = $this->getMockBuilder('User')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();` we can just say `$args['User'] = new User;` and get the same error.

Now, let's look at what we're doing:

1. We create an associative array, mapping class names to (mock) objects
2. We pass that associative array to a Mock Builder's `setConstructorArgs` method
3. Some magic happens...

So, what *does* happen? Maybe [the source of PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) will give some clues.

Well, [`setConstructorArgs` just sets a property](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.14/src/Framework/MockObject/MockBuilder.php#L320), which is [used in `getMock`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.14/src/Framework/MockObject/MockBuilder.php#L111), then passed through a bunch of different methods; eventually, it ends up passed to [`MockObject\Generator::getObject`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/1883687169c017d6ae37c58883ca3994cfc34189/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L585), which if we strip out some error handling, does this:

```php
$class = new ReflectionClass($className);
$object = $class->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
```

So, let's see if we can use that to make an **even more minimal example** of our problem:

```php
class User {}

class Example {
     public User $user;

     public function __construct(User $user) {
          $this->user = $user;
     }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass(Example::class);
$object = $class->newInstanceArgs(['User' => new User]);
```

Since this is self-contained code, we can use the handy online tool at https://3v4l.org to compare output in different PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/QU4jS

As expected, PHP 7.4 is happy with it, PHP 8.0 and above give an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $User in /in/QU4jS:14
Stack trace:
#0 /in/QU4jS(14): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /in/QU4jS on line 14
```

So, what is going on here? Well, [the manual page for `ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) doesn't (currently) say much about what the provided array should look like, or named argument support, but we can take an educated guess: it's trying to match our associative array as named parameters to the constructor. Previous versions, since they had no named parameters, simply ignored the keys and applied the parameters in order.

We can test this theory easily enough by making a class with two parameters to its constructor:

```
class Example2 {
    public function __construct($first, $second) {
        echo "$first then $second\n";
    }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass(Example2::class);
$object = $class->newInstanceArgs(['second' => 'two', 'first' => 'one']);
```

When [run on multiple versions](https://3v4l.org/X0kaH) we can see that older versions of PHP output "two then one", based on the *order* of the array; and newer versions output "one then two", based on the *keys* of the array.

---

So, to cut a long story short, what's the fix? Quite simply, don't use keys in the array of constructor parameters:

```
class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
     public function testExample() {
          $args = [];
          $args[] = new User;

          $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Example::class)
                ->setConstructorArgs($args)
                ->getMock();

          $this->assertTrue(true);
      }
}
```

If you need to use them during the setup logic to keep track of things, just use [`array_values`](https://php.net/array_values) to discard them when you pass them in:

```
class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
     public function testExample() {
          $args = [];
          $args['User'] = new User;

          $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Example::class)
                ->setConstructorArgs(array_values($args))
                ->getMock();

          $this->assertTrue(true);
      }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Suspected it was the array key  behavior change but haven't been up to speed on changes in 8.

Comment: @IMSop Excellent answer, thank you! Digging into the innards of getMock was quite a maze and an answer didn't immediately jump out at me - but obviously I was not approaching it right. Breaking it down into simpler, more straight to the point code was brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I had another case, where I got the same error: "Unknown named parameter $validation_result_expected".

I used a data provider where I defined a key which had another name (`'validation_result_expected'`) than the related method parameter of the test method (`$validationResultExpected`).
After fixing the provider key name to `validationResultExpected` no error occured anymore.

This problem is not exactly related to the OP problem. But the error message was the same. When I searched for the error message, this was the first entry. Therefor I added my answer to this question.